# AJAX sincrónico

Tags: javascript, ajax, mvc, promesas, async

Estoy llenando 3 DropDownList en cascada "Estados, Municipios, Colonias" con MVC 5, estos deben ser llenados si o si desde el controller, javascript solo puedo usarlo para setearlo, con un *partialView* por cada combo logre que se actualicen en cascada, pero las llamadas AJAX asincronas no se ejecuta siempre en el mismo orden, por lo que esto me genera errores al querer setear un combo que aun no existe.

**El orden correcto de mis 6 funciones es este**

- GetEstados()
- SetEstados()
- GetMunicipios(IdEstado)
- SetMunicipios()
- GetColonias(IdEstado,IdMunicipio)
- SetColonias()

**He intentado:**

- Usar **Callback**, pero continua ejecutando mis funciones en orden aleatorio.
- Usar **Promises de Js**, pero también se ejecutan las funciones en orden aleatorio.
- He declarado **async: false**, esto hace que el AJAX se ejecute de forma sincrona por ende respeta el orden de ejecución y funciona, pero el explorador me envía esta alerta: ***SignalR: el XMLHttpRequest síncrono en el hilo principal está en desuso*** ademas de que leyendo dicen que esto no es optimo para el usuario

  **NOTA:** No debo construir los DropDownList directamente por JavaScript.

¿Que otra alternativa tengo para ejecutar las funciones de manera sincrona?

Tengo el siguiente código muestra:

```
          var modelo = $('#form1').serialize();
          //Codigo funcion GetEstados()
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/SolicitudDeCredito/cbo_Estados",
                data: modelo,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#div_Estados").html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    Console.log('Error en GetEstados()');
                }
            });

           //Codigo funcion SetEstados() - Recupera el IdEstado
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/SolicitudDeCredito/Get_IdEstado",
                data: { "CP": document.getElementById("Cp").value },
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != "") {
                        document.getElementById("iIdEstado").value = data;
                        //ARR: Llena el DropDownList de Estados, enviando el IdEstado que deberá Seleccionar.
                        document.getElementById("cbo_Estados").value = document.getElementById("iIdEstado").value;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("iIdEstado").value = "-1";
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                   Console.log('Error en SetEstados()');
                }
            });
```

Gracias por su apoyo, saludos !!!

Comment: Has pensado en guardar cada consulta en una funcion y en el success de tu primera llamada ajax ejecutar la siguiente y asi por el estilo

Comment: Antes de ejecutar el primer ajax puedes obtener el dato de Cp ?

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. No entiendo bien tu pregunta. Supongo que los `select` se actualizarían en cascada. O sea, seleccionas 1º un `país` y se cargan todos los estados de ese país, 2º seleccionas un `estado` y se cargan todos los municipios de ese estado, 3º seleccionas un `municipio` y se cargan todas las colonias de ese municipio. Cada una de esas llamadas al servidor se haría en el `onchange` de cada `select`. No veo por qué hayas de tener problemas con eso. ¿El contexto es como explico o es diferente? ¿Lo estás planteando así o no? Es necesario que seas más claro en tu planteamiento.

Comment: He anidado los ajax pero continuan ejecutandose de forma aleatorea, ya cuento con el Cp antes de ejecutar las funciones, pienso que podría optimizar de 6 a solo 4 funciones si antes de llenar los catalogos, recupero los Id de los 3 combos, así disminuiria el tiempo de carga y por ende el tiempo en que se congela la pantalla durante la carga sincrona.

Comment: @A.Cedano los 3 select se actualizan en cascasda con el evento onchange como mencionas, el problema es que no existe el combo hasta que no se ejecutan primero estas funciones, al ser vistas parciales cada funcion me devuelve el combo en html ya cargado, este lo asigno a un div, posterior a esto ejecuto una segunda funcion que recupera el Id seleccionado por el usuario, si esto no se ejecuta en ese orden, me envía errores al intentar seleccionar un Id en un combo que no existe todavía, espero haberme podido explicar, gracias por tu apoyo, saludos !!!

Comment: Alex si es como dices el problema es más bien en la lógica que estás implementando. No veo óptimo un código en el cual tengas que estar construyendo y destruyendo los `select` constantemente (como elementos que son parte del DOM). ¿Por qué no creas todos los `select` desde el principio, dejando activado solamente el 1º y activando los otros de forma sucesiva. Según comentas en cada cambio destruyes y vuelves a crear los elementos. Es una mala idea, es mejor que los `select` existan y simplemente en cada onchange cambias la lista de opciones. No sé si me entiendes.

Comment: @A.Cedano exacto este ejemplo que muestro es únicamente durante la carga del formulario, si ya cuento con un CP automaticamente construyo los 3 combos, en caso de no tener un CP solo construyo el 1er combo de Estados y los otros 2 los dejo vacios, para que se vayan llenando en cascadas despues del onchange de un combo anterior, si cambia un CP o el combo de Estado, esto le afectará a toda la cascada y es cuando vuelve a iniciar la carga de los 3 combos, pero solo en ese caso, ahora mismo acabo de terminar una funcion para recuperar todos los Id en una sola llamada al servidor, haré pruebas

Answer (score 2):

No te quedan muchas opciones debido a las condiciones que comentas.

El hecho de que el navegador haga esa advertencia es normal, pero no es malo. Es simplemente un aviso.

El caso es que su uso esta desaconsejado precisamente por la UX (experiencia de usuario) y es que lo que va a ocurrir (con peticiones sincronas) es que hasta que no se devuelvan los resultados de la primera llamada AJAX, no se hará la petición de tu segunda llamada, pero eso es precisamente lo que necesitas. No te debes preocupar demasiado (a priori) por este asunto, ya que el problema que se desea evitar en estos casos es que la primera consulta se demore y no se ejecute el codigo de las posteriores consultas. Sin embargo, esto es algo que suele ocurrir con muy poca frecuencia. De todas las veces que he tenido que ejecutar peticiones AJAX de forma sincrona, nunca he tenido problemas en este sentido.

Entonces, tus dos opciones (que ahora mismo se me ocurran) son:

- Hacer que tu consulta sea sincrona (añadiendo esa propiedad a tu metodo AJAX):

  ```
  async:false
  ```
- Anidar las consultas AJAX una dentro de la otra. Es decir, en el metodo success de tu primera consulta, haces la segunda consulta, y asi con las demas. Si bien esta forma de trabajar es asincrona, a todos los efectos la estas forzando a realizarse igual que una consulta hecha de forma sincrona, con el inconveniente de que en tu caso, el anidamiento podría hacer el codigo incomodo de trabajar con el, o bien, confuso. Esto lo harías así:

  ```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/SolicitudDeCredito/cbo_Estados",
      data: modelo,
      //en este caso no necesitas hacer sincrona. 
      success: function (data) {
          //aquí metes tu segunda consulta
          $.ajax({
          .
          .
          .
          });
      },
      error: function () {
      Console.log('Error en GetEstados()');
  }
  });
  ```

Comment: Ambos casos ya los he implementado y si es cierto que con async:false se resuelve todo el problema, quise pedir una segunda opinión con ustedes, en todo caso lo que debo hacer es optimizar las consultas a base de datos al máximo, para evitar que la pantalla se congele demasiado tiempo durante la fase de carga para el usuario, respecto al anidamiento de ajax ya intente ese método pero de cualquier forma los ejecuta de forma aleatorea, muchas gracias por tu ayuda !!!

Answer (score 0):

AJAX recupera los datos de forma asíncorna y los devolverá conforme sean recuperados, sin un orden predefinido.

Para que la consulta se de en cascada lo que te recomiendo es colocar las llamadas AJAX en forma anidada, es decir, colonias al interior de municipios y municipios al interior de estados.

Esto hará que los llamados devuelvan colonias luego de municipios y municipios luego de estados.

En resumen, coloca los llamados AJAX de menor jerarquia en los callbacks de los de mayor jerarquía.

Comment: esto parece mas un comentario extendido que una respuesta en si, revisa [answer] pues es importante no solo decirle que debe hacer si no también el como, para que tu respuesta sea considerada de calidad

Comment: La API de `XMLHttpRequest` sí permite peticiones síncronas por medio de un parámetro booleano en el constructor; sin embargo, no es para nada recomendable.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, de echo eso también ya lo intente, anidar los ajax, yo esperaba que se ejecutarán desde adentro hacia afuera, para eso puse mensajes de Console.Log para identificar el orden de ejecución y desgraciadamente por algún motivo las ejecuta en orden aleatorio.